# SQL server 2012 slow when ram is near max allowed for sql

Tags: sql-server-2012, virtual-machine, temp-tables, sqlperformance

Its been a month since this problem started and i haven't found the cause or a solution for the problem.

I have a visual basic program to view our business inteligence quering an sql server 2012.

The host has 48GB of memory, shared with 2 VM's:

- Virtual machine SQL- 32 GB, 24 Reserved,26GB max sql setting.
- Virtual machine Terminal Services - 12 GB Ram

When the memory of the VM SQL reaches around 90% a sudden drop of performance is observed. Queries that normally take 2 secs go to 30-40 secs.

If i restart SQL everything goes fine for the next 2-3 days. Editing the max server memory in SSMS  for up or down also does the trick.

UPDATE:

WHEN SERVER IS FAST:

[image: sql server]
[image: sql server]
[image: settings]
[image: sql server]
[image: windows server 2012 SQL VM]
[image: windows server 2012 SQL VM]

```
    SELECT counter_name, instance_name, mb = cntr_value/1024.0
  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
  WHERE (counter_name = N'Cursor memory usage' and instance_name <> N'_Total')
  OR (instance_name = N'' AND counter_name IN 
       (N'Connection Memory (KB)', N'Granted Workspace Memory (KB)', 
        N'Lock Memory (KB)', N'Optimizer Memory (KB)', N'Stolen Server Memory (KB)', 
        N'Log Pool Memory (KB)', N'Free Memory (KB)')
  ) ORDER BY mb DESC;
```

[image]

FUTURE UPDATE:

WHEN SERVER IS SLOW: TO BE UPDATED

Any ideas?

Thanks

Pedro

Comment: There might be a swapping going on. Can you check memory stat according to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89834/sql-server-2012-memory-consumption-outside-the-buffer-pool ?

Comment: Is there anything else installed on the SQL VM?  Are you using SSAS as well as the relational engine?

Comment: hey @Nat i did the change in max server setting this morning so that people could work, so the values im going to insert are not when the system is slow.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth we got the sql server and the business software installed in the VM. I recently read that these two systems should be seperated.

Comment: what does does the free memory in last screenshot refer to? i can see it has lowered 200MB in half a day

Comment: @cannondale, can you try to follow this procedure to lock pages in memory? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918483

Comment: Hey @Nat. Our sql runs using local sql account. Like SA. how can this lock be done ?

Comment: @cannondale, Local account is ok. You can just follow the step in the above link. Also refer to this document if you use Hyper-V, http://sqlmag.com/database-virtualization/using-hyper-v-dynamic-memory-sql-server